# d3.js and coffeescript - reading binded data in string interpolation

Tags: d3.js, coffeescript

Let's consider data to be binded to some object:

```
sample = ["x": "1", "y": "1"]
```

as simple as possible, now i do

```
d3.select("#someContainer")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(sample)
  .enter()
  .attr(
    "value_taking_y": (d) -> d.y
    "value_taking_x": "someValue#{(d) -> d.x}"
  )
```

Problem i'm getting is that "value_taking_y" got right value, it is d.y, but "value_taking_x" is evaluated to something like "someValuefunction(d){return d.x}" which is obviously not intended by me. 
On the other hand if i force evaluation of this function in the first place by adding word "do" then i got error similiar to "d is not known value", which seems to be good behavior in this situation.

I'd appreciate some help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you intending `"someValue#{(d) -> d.x}"` to do?

Comment: @muistooshort i wanted to create string "someValue" concatenated with value d.x

Comment: Then why wouldn't you say `(d) -> "someValue#{d.x}"`? `(d) -> ...` is a function definition after all.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you, thats smart